# Do Ewoks only eat people on special occasions?

Tags: star-wars, ewoks

An often glossed over point of Return of the Jedi is the fact that the cute fluffy Ewoks plan to cook and eat the rebels as the main course in a “celebratory feast”. Has this aspect of Ewok culture been expanded on in any medium? Was this a one off for their “god” (C3P0) or did the Ewoks regularly hunt and eat other sentient species? Also why not also eat Leia (or were they fattening her up for a future meal)?

Comment: Surely having people over for dinner *is*  a special occasion?

Comment: [This might interest you](http://insidepulse.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/STAR-WARS-SHATTERED-EMPIRE-1-CP3O-Ewoks.jpg). It's left ambiguous, but the writer probably knew what he was doing

Comment: Pigs, cattle, chickens, and fish are sentient species.

Comment: @user14111 Not by the Star Wars definition.

Comment: @RogueJedi *Star Wars* has its own definition of sentience? What is it? Is it the same as the *Star Trek* definition?

Comment: @user14111 Yes, most soft  science fiction uses a popular definition of sentience which more closely equates to "sapience" in the real world.

Comment: @user14111 http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sentience

Comment: @RogueJedi Thanks for the reference.